# Help with a compiler warning: Initialization from distinct Objective-C type when types match

Tags: objective-c, iphone, oop, compiler-warnings

Here is the function where I get the compiler warning, I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Any help is appreciated.

```
 -(void)displaySelector{
    //warning on the following line:
    InstanceSelectorViewController *controller = [[InstanceSelectorViewController alloc] initWithCreator:self];
    [self.navController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Interface and implementation for the initWithCreator: method

```
-(InstanceSelectorViewController*)initWithCreator:(InstanceCreator*)creator;


-(InstanceSelectorViewController*)initWithCreator:(InstanceCreator*)crt{
    if (self = [self initWithNibName:@"InstanceSelectorViewController" bundle:nil]) {
        creator = crt;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I remember getting this error and the problem being that i hadn't imported a header file i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is not the only class in your project that has an `initWithCreator:` method. In general, it is a bad idea to give static types to init methods. `alloc` returns `id`, so the compiler doesn't know the type of the object you're sending the init method to. If there's more than one choice, it will often guess wrong, and you'll get the warning you see.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what the problem is. My fix based on your answer was to cast the type when I called initWithCreator:

 InstanceCreatorViewController *controller = [(InstanceCreatorViewController*)[InstanceCreatorViewController alloc] initWithCreator:self];

Comment: that cast had an asterix in it, not sure where it went.

Comment: @Alex Gosselin: Stack Overflow uses Markdown, which parses text between asterisks as emphasized. To have code formatted properly, place it between backticks. So it would be (backtick) `InstanceCreatorViewController *controller = [(InstanceCreatorViewController*)[InstanceCreatorViewController alloc] initWithCreator:self];` (backtick).

Comment: Haha my friend you have all the answers.